# Trying to override Magento core model resource

Tags: magento, resources, overriding

I'm trying to override

```
Mage/Eav/Model/Resource/Entity/attribute.php
```

with this in config.xml:

```
...
<models>
   ....
   <eav_resource>
      <rewrite>                   
         <entity_attribute>
                  Mymodule_Eav_Model_Resource_Entity_Attribute
         </entity_attribute>
      </rewrite>
   </eav_resource>
</models>
...
```

But it doesn't seem to work. My file is at:

```
/app/code/local/Mymodule/Eav/Model/Resource/Entity/Attribute.php
```

and starts with:

```
class Mymodule_Eav_Model_Resource_Entity_Attribute 
         extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract
{
  ...
```

Any ideas why is isn't working?

Looks like it does work, but this is what's happening:

```
2013-11-19T15:07:15+00:00 DEBUG (7): construct Mymodule_Eav_Model_Resource_Entity_Attribute
2013-11-19T15:07:15+00:00 DEBUG (7): construct Mage_Eav_Model_Resource_Entity_Attribute
2013-11-19T15:07:19+00:00 DEBUG (7): construct Mage_Eav_Model_Resource_Entity_Attribute
```

so, when I save:
`2013-11-19T15:09:09+00:00 DEBUG (7): Mage_Eav_Model_Resource_Entity_Attribute _saveOption` called.

instead of: `Mymodule_Eav_Model_Resource_Entity_Attribute _saveOption()`

Comment: I might be wrong, but I suppose it's nothing to do with parent class being an abstract class

Comment: Not sure if this is it, but you should remove the spaces along the class name. I mean use it like this `<entity_attribute>Mymodule_Eav_Model_Resource_Entity_Attribute</entity_attribute>`. Magento does not trim the spaces and new lines from the rewrite class names

Comment: Thanks, but it's not. I put those spaces here for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you cleared the configuration cache, and make sure your module is coming up in System->Configuration->Advanced->Disable Modules Output

Comment: I did both. No change. If instead of making the changes in my module I override Magento's model putting the code in local folder everything works fine.